# how can we route two routers on one switch in a different network ip

Tags: routing

I am trying to connect two routers in one switch to ping each other using IP route .

[image: upload]

```
router 0 has 192.168.10.1/24 gi0/0
router 1 has 192.168.20.1/24 gi0/0
```

I tried putting switch-port trunks on both fa0/1 and fa0/2 for switch 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two routers to communicate with each other they need to share a common network (across the switch in your diagram).

So, using e.g. `192.168.10.1/16` and `192.168.20.1/16` (or up to /18) would work, while `192.168.10.1/24` and `192.168.20.1/24` will not.

Comment: So basically 1 switch holds 1 network to communicate and it is not possible to do routing on different networks connecting 1 switch to 2 routers? Even it has ip route? Thanks Zac

Comment: For two parties on *different* networks to communicate, you need a *router* in between. *Switches* allow two parties to communicate *in the same network*. Setting up (static or dynamic) routes enables communication beyond the two routers, not between them.

Comment: Thanks alot now i know the use of switches and routers on this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Both the routers has to share same network subnet to ensure communication between two router's ..

For example

1 ) 192.168.10.1/24 for first router
2) 192.168.10.2/24 for second router

Then both router will communicate..